# A new input field adding with dropdown value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

1. When a user clicks the  "+" button, then a row should be added with a dropdown and input field. I want to make that input field name as a dropdown value for each rows.
2. If I select "facebook" in first dropdown, it should not show in the second dropdown list. simply selecting values should NOT display in next dropdown. I done that part. But my question is if I select "Google" in second dropdown, "Yahoo" in third dropdown. and again if i click the first or second dropdown it should NOT display the "Yahoo" again.

Please find the link below where the code is present and fix it.

http://jsfiddle.net/mhmdsohail/v9uem13u/5/

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.add-more', function (e) {
    var lastSelect = $("select").last().find('option');
    var toAppend = '';
    if (lastSelect.length > 1) {
        toAppend += '<select name="select[]">';
        $.each(lastSelect, function (i, v) {
            if ($(this).text() !== $("select:last option:selected").text())
                toAppend += '<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).text() + '</option>';
        });
        toAppend += '</select>';
        toAppend += '<input type="text" name=""><br>';
    }
    $(".append-select").append(toAppend);
});
```

Comment: Post your html code here

Comment: @MayankPandey Please check http://jsfiddle.net/mhmdsohail/v9uem13u/5/

Comment: you should include selection change handling in your code. that makes helping you a lot less work. I also recommend to inlcude an array to specify possible options.. this way you wont have to parse the DOM during selection changes, e.g. var options = [{name: "Facebook", inUse=true}, {...}, ...]

Comment: It is tricky to understand this one.
Can you please give us some example use cases?
1- User selects an item in the dropdown list and presses +. A new row is added which does not included the initial selected item. What happens with the first dropdown list? Do you also need to delete the selected item?
2- " But my question is if I select "Google" in second dropdown, "Yahoo" in third dropdown. and again if i click the first or second dropdown it should NOT display the "Yahoo" again" It should not display yahoo where? In the previous dropdown menus?

Comment: @GokhanDilek I need the output as below image
http://acmsohail.com/error.jpg

Initially it display all values (Facebook, Google, Yahoo, Whatsapp, Youtube) in first dropdown. You select "Facebook" in the first dropdown. And click the "+" to add a row. In the second dropdown "Facebook" is not display Its working fine. Likewise if you select Google in second dropdown, then "facebook and google" dont display in third dropdown. But the issue is again if u go back and select the first dropdown it keep showing the "google". Whatever u selected in the dropdown it SHOULD NOT display in otherdropdown

Comment: @user3671027 Do you want to only add the row using the first dropdown list? Or you can add a row using any dropdown list?

Comment: @GokhanDilek you can add a row using any dropdown list. But each row dropdown should NOT display the selected dropdown values in other dropdowns.

Client requirement is there are several social media links that user can select from the dropdown and can enter the url. But social media list is more than 16. Thatswhy I thought to put a dropdown and a input field to take the url for that particular dropdown values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JavaScript code does what you're asking for:

*(From what I understood. This will removed selected option from all current `dropdowns` (and future ones as well) and the next input field will contain attribute `name` with a value equal to last selected `dropdown` option)*

```
 $(document.body).on('click', '.add-more', function (e) {
                var lastSelect = $("select").last().find('option');
                var selectedOption = $('select:last').val();
                var toAppend = '';
                if (lastSelect.length > 1) {
                    toAppend += '<select name="select[]">';
                    $.each(lastSelect, function (i, v) {
                        if ($(this).text() !== $("select:last option:selected").text())
                            toAppend += '<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).text() + '</option>';
                    });
                    toAppend += '</select>';
                    toAppend += '<input type="text" name="' + selectedOption + '"><br>';
                }
                $(".append-select").append(toAppend);
                if ($('select:last > option').length > 1)
                        $("select").find('option[value=' + selectedOption + ']').remove();
            });
```

I have tried to minimize as many changes as possible (only 3 or 4 lines were edited).

Comment: Your answer is partially correct. But it didn't display the selected dropdown in each rows.
My requirement is users can't select the same dropdown values in new rows. Dropdown values can be select only a single time in entire form also it should display in the dropdown.

Example If i select facebook in first dropdown, google in second dropdown. Again if i click the facebook dropdown it SHOULD NOT allows to select google again. but currently its allowing. how to avoid it. I need the output as like this.
http://acmsohail.com/error.jpg

Comment: @user3671027 I noticed you response as well as your email. Don't worry about that. Just solving a few other things at the same time. :)

Comment: Thanks in advance. Please help me to sort it out.